# How can I get a connection string from a text file?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have developed a Windows application with the backend of SQL Server to insert employee names. I am going to insert the employee details on three databases one by one. So, I like to get connecting values from text file. Whenever I want to change the connection, I just want to enter the login details in the text file.

How can I get a connection string from a text file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plaese try like this

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test 
{

    public static void Main() 
    {
        string txtpath = @"c:\textfile.txt";
        try 
        {
            if (File.Exists(txtpath)) 
            {



            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(txtpath)) 
            {
                while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
                {
                    string ss = sr.ReadLine();
                     string [] txtsplit = ss.Split(';');

                     //now loop through   array
                     string server=txtsplit[0].Tostring();
                    string userid= split[1].Tostring(); // user id
                   string password= split[2].Tostring(); // password

                }
            }
          }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi regon.. where i have to write this code in program.cs or any other page

Comment: No, This is the way to extract string from text File.You have to write this code where you define the connection string.

Answer (score 5):

Use an `app.config` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xtk877y.aspx)) file.

Allows you to configure multiple named connection strings which you can access via the [System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) class' [ConnectionStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings.aspx) property

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need to use plain text file to do this. There is a special configuration file you can use and a set of classes to make your life easier.

**Add configuration file to you project**

Go to Add new item in the solution and select Application Configuration File

**Add connection strings to the configuration file**

Just copy / paste this and modify connection string and connection string name as needed

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Conn1" connectionString="Data Source=SERVER_NAME;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USER;Password=12345678" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="Conn2" connectionString="Data Source=SERVER_NAME;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USER;Password=12345678" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

**Add System.Configuration reference to your project**

Right click references, go to add new and select System.Configuration from .NET tab

**Add wrapper class**

This is not needed but it will make your life easier. Create a class like this so you don’t have to call configuration manager every time you need to connect to database

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Text;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    class Config
    {
        public static string CONNECTION_STRING_1
        {
            get
            {
                return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn1"].ConnectionString;
            }
        }

        public static string CONNECTION_STRING_2
        {
            get
            {
                return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn2"].ConnectionString;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Use connection strings in other methods like this**

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Config.CONNECTION_STRING_1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Sql
{
    public static string ReadCS()
    {
        using (var streamReader = File.OpenText("SqlSettings.txt"))//Enter FileName
        {
            var lines = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            return lines;
        }
    }
            
    public SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Sql.ReadCS());
}
```